# Filepond Upload Status shows "Upload Complete" before the file is uploaded

Tags: filepond

Because S3 upload functions upload the file asynchronously, the filepond method shows file status as "Upload Complete" until its completely uploaded. Is there a way to create a dependency to not do anything until the file is completely uploaded to S3?

[Log to show it shows Upload Complete but S3 logs shows its still uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btF5X.png)

Answer (score 1):

If the S3 service returns a 200 OK to the file form post FilePond assumes the upload has completed.

To resolve this you can set up a custom processing method to finetune the upload process: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#process-1